# maxfilesexceeded event is not firing in dropzone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropzone.js

This seems a very strange issue. All other events are fired but not these two. Maybe `maxFiles` is also not working and eventually these events are not firing. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;
  Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 5,
    maxFiles: 1,
    accept: function(file, done) {
      console.log("done");
    },
    init: function(){
      console.log(this); //WORKS
      this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
         alert("sdf"); //DOESN'T WORK
      });
      this.on("maxfilesreached", function(file){
         alert("sdf"); //DOESN'T WORK
      });
      this.on("addedfile", function(file){
        console.log("added", file); //WORKS
      });
    }
  };
});

<div class="container">
  <div class="login-form">
    <h3>Login to Conversation</h3>
    <form action="test.php" class="form-inline dropzone" id="my-dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="file" type="file" class="form-control">
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 5,
    maxFiles: 1,
    maxfilesexceeded: function(file) {
      console.log('exceeded')
    },
    maxfilesreached: function(file) {
      console.log('reached')
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {
      console.log("done");
    }
  };
});
```